# redux-form only show validation errors on submit

Tags: redux-form

Is there a way to configure redux-form so that validation errors only show when the form is submitted?

Also I would like to clear an individual form field error when a user starts typing or makes a change.

Is this possible with redux-form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're responsible for rendering any validation errors, so you can configure them only to be visible after submission has failed (i.e. the user pressed submit and your validations came back as failing). For this, your [input components wrapped with `Field`](http://redux-form.com/6.8.0/docs/api/Field.md/) are passed a `meta` object as a prop that contains a `submitFailed` field that tells whether form submission has failed. The actual code for rendering that component could look something like this:

```
render() {
  const { meta: { error, submitFailed } } = this.props
  return (
    // ... rendering the input and then some
    { error && submitFailed ? (
      <span className="validation-error">{ error }</span>
    ) : null }
    // ... rendering the rest
  )
}
```

For not showing errors while the user is typing, you're responsible for enabling that behavior and the props passed to your wrapped input component hold the keys, this time the `meta` object holds a field called `active`, which tells you whether this input has focus or not. Code could be something like this (building on the previous example):

```
render() {
  const { meta: { active, error, submitFailed } } = this.props
  return (
    // ... rendering the input and then some
    { !active && (error && submitFailed) ? (
      <span className="validation-error">{ error }</span>
    ) : null }
    // ... rendering the rest
  )
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also had this problem, the reason was using **touchOnChange** flag

```
reduxForm({
        form: 'MyForm',
        enableReinitialize: true,
        touchOnChange: true,
})
```

So I removed this flag from **reduxForm** options and the code started working correctly - I saw the validation errors on submit only

```
reduxForm({
        form: 'MyForm',
        enableReinitialize: true,
})
```

Example from official site
https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/